# Java thread.getContext().getClassLoader() uniqueness

Tags: java, multithreading, classloader

How unique is the thread context's classloader. Is it reset everytime a thread is started?
Can we always be sure that 2 parallel threads will never have the same context classloader?
I see some frameworks like Axis relying on this to get and set run-time setting variables.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader--. It answers your question.

Comment: Yeah. In a typical web application, all the threads are already created by the container. So according to the documentation, if they inherit the creater's classloader, are we to assume all threads in say jboss have the same application server class loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How unique is the thread context's classloader.

Not even remotely.

> Is it reset everytime a thread is started?

When a thread is created, it doesn’t have context loader that can be reset. It will inherit the parent thread’s context loader. Starting the thread doesn’t change its context loader.

> Can we always be sure that 2 parallel threads will never have the same context classloader?

That would be actually very unlikely. As said, threads inherit the parent’s loader by default, so unless someone calls `setContextClassLoader` explicitly with a different loader, the default application class loader, as returned by [`ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader--) will be the used by all threads. Even in environments with different class loaders, it’s unlikely to have as much class loaders as threads.

> I see some frameworks like Axis relying on this to get and set run-time setting variables.

It’s the main use of the feature, frameworks using the current thread’s context class loader *by convention*, but of course, for loading classes and resources, not to assume uniqueness of these loaders. The JVM never uses this context class loader on its own, as symbolic references found in a class are resolved through the *defining class loader* of that class. The same applies for `Class.forName(String)` (without a class loader argument). It requires code actively invoking `getContextClassLoader()` and using the returned loader for class loading, to make this feature relevant.

Don’t confuse class loaders with [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variables.

Comment: Thanks Holger. If you get a chance, please look at apache's common discovery jar. This will contain ManagerProperties class. Check the setProperties method where getContextClassLoader is used as a key in a HashMap. This is used by axis framework to set runtime properties like SSLSecureFactory. We have a challenge in the application, which I have posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435681/axisproperties-setproperty-scope

Comment: I don’t have that source code here, but what you described sounds plausible, as you are setting a property to a *class name* that has to be resolved against a specific class loader, so the result may be cached in respect to the class loader, as class loaders are supposed to return the same class for the same name, whereas a different class loader may resolve the same name to a different class. That does not necessarily imply that supporting different values for different threads is intended, only that the context of the caller of `setProperty` determines the meaning of the class name.

Comment: The code is static void setProperty(String propertyName, String value, boolean isDefault){
    synchronized (propertiesCache) {
      ClassLoader classLoader = getThreadContextClassLoader();
      HashMap properties = (HashMap)propertiesCache.get(classLoader);      
      if (value == null) {
        properties.remove(propertyName);
      } else {
        if (properties == null) {
          properties = new HashMap();
          propertiesCache.put(classLoader, properties);
        }        
        properties.put(propertyName, new Value(value, isDefault));
      }    
  }
}

Comment: May be they are using the class loader to resolve the class at some place. In an app server, the threads area already created and assigned for each request. So like you said they cannot be used for thread safe values. I believe there will be a racing condition when 2 threads, set same properties (with different values) using a syntax like below?